# Domain is locally path-connected if image of a covering map is locally path-connected.

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, connectedness

Show that if $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is a covering map and $Y$ is locally path-connected, then so is $X$.

How do you go about proving this? I can think of two ways of doing this, either by definition of locally path-connected and covering map or by trying to use the lift.

I've tried writing out the definitions of both concepts but even then, I don't see how I can "pull back" the path-connected set into the domain.

Comment: I think I just got it. Is it because of the homeomorphic property of the restriction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ and $V$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. There is an evenly covered open neighborhood $U$ of $p(x)$. Say $x\in U_\alpha$ and $p_\alpha:U_\alpha\to U$ is the restriction of $p$ and a homeomorphism. Then $V\cap U_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to $p(V\cap U_\alpha)$. This is an open set containing $p(x)$, so it contains a path-connected neighborhood $W$. You can then just take the preimage of $W$ under $p_\alpha$.

**Remark:** The local (path-)connectedness of $X$ makes $Y$ local (path-)connected, too, which is very easy to prove since $p$ is continuous and open. But it can be shown that even a quotient map carries over the local (path-)connectedness from the domain to the image. (This is not difficult either, if you use the right characterization of local connectedness.)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what you mean by "evenly covered open neighbourhood"?

Comment: It's a common expression for an open neighborhood $U$ such that the preimage is a disjoint union of open sets, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$. I don't find the term in my Algebraic Topology book, but it is used here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition